# Ng-Repeat With Changing Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using `ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index"` to repeat a specific number of times which is defined by a `select` object in HTML.

```
var number = parseInt($( "#number option:selected" ).text());
        $scope.myNumber = number;
        $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
            return new Array(num);   
        }
```

It works perfectly. Now, I want it to update when I change the `#number option:selected` though. The `var number` receives this by doing something like this `$( "#number" ).change(function() {});`, but even when I put the above code block in there, the `ng-repeat` only changes onload.

How can I use `ng-repeat` with a changing variable?

Comment: can you create fiddle with your code?

Comment: Without the full code, it's hard to get an exact answer to you. If you are setting the value from code behind, is it just that you need to use apply or digest? http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just watch the iteration number like this:

```
$scope.iteration = new Array(2);
$scope.$watch('repeat_num',function(new_val) {
    if (new_val) {
        $scope.iteration = new Array(parseInt($scope.repeat_num));
    }  
});
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="repeat_num">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in iteration track by $index">Value</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a jQuery event handler, as it the event will not trigger a digest cycle unless you tell it to. You can just supply the select box a ng-model, and a digest cycle will automatically be started on a change of the select to update the bindings.

```
<select ng-model="myNumber">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)">
    I am at index: {{$index}}
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c726z0r/)